# Microsoft Fabric (pySpark) - Inferschema on dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to use inferschema after the data has been loaded into a dataframe?
The reason why is because the data in my json file is not properly structured. I need to modify the structure before defining the schema, as the output of "spark.read.json(...)" is already a dataframe.

**Raw:**
[image]

**Edited Raw:**
[image]

**Schema of edited Raw:**
[image]

Comment: If you read data using `spark.read.json`, the output will be in form of a dataframe with a fixed schema. The schema is either inferred by spark engine or is defined and imposed by you. If you wanna manipulate the json content before putting data in a structured format, you can read the json file using `spark.read.txt` API, manipulate the text content, then either impose schema using `from_json` API or write out the text and read it back using `spark.read.json` API.